# How to synchronize two RichEdit's scrolling position?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, vcl, richedit

I add my program two RichEdit which the one displays binary contents and the another shows the index of the byte. I hope these two edit always anchor on the same position while/after scrolling.

[image]

A possible way is to handle the main RichEdit's WM_VSCROLL and WM_MOUSEWHEEL message and pass the message and parameters to the second RichEdit. I've tried this but I found that the two edits aligned not very well. And the other disadvantage is the both RichEdits' scroll bar needs to be enabled, if I only enable one, the another can't receive WM_MOUSEWHEEL message, but I hope one scroll bar displayed only.

[image]

The second way I've tried is using a timer and synchronize with LINESCROLL regularly by the time (< 10ms is better). This works well most of the time, but sometimes still have the unaligned issue.

Is there a better solution to handle this kind of demand?

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TBinaryEdit::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
    int srcLine = 0;
    int trgLine = 0;

    if (Sender == Timer1) {
        srcLine = GetRichEditLineNo(MainEdit);
        trgLine = GetRichEditLineNo(IndexEdit);

        if (srcLine != trgLine) {
            SendMessage(IndexEdit->Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, srcLine - trgLine);
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int TBinaryEdit::GetRichEditLineNo(TRichEdit* RE)
{
    int line;
    int wordpos;

    TRect rt;
    POINTL pt;

    SendMessage(RE->Handle, EM_GETRECT, 0, LPARAM(&rt));
    pt.x = RE->Left + rt.left;
    pt.y = RE->Top + rt.top;
    wordpos = SendMessage(RE->Handle, EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, LPARAM(&pt));
    line = SendMessage(RE->Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, wordpos, 0);

    return line;
}
```

Comment: Are you writing a hex editor?
https://github.com/bonecode/BCHexEditor

Comment: To Miller: Yes I am. Furthermore I hope to have Find, Replace and allows direct editing hex on the editor. I'll reference to the link you provided, thank you very much.

Comment: Synchronize WM_SCROLL messages should be enough if implemented correctly. Anyways, if you after creating hex editor you might find it useful: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1271133/MFC-HEX-Control

Comment: Why shoehorn RichEdit into this? It's not really suited to this application.

Comment: I would not use separate edit controls for this. A single edit control will suffice, simply give it extra margin space on the left side using `EM_SETMARGINS` or `EM_SETRECT`, and then subclass the edit control to custom-draw the byte offsets within that space. Or, the simplest solution is to just add the byte offsets to the front of the text lines that you add to the edit control. But, if you really want to sync 2 edit controls, have a look at [this discussion](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21137299/add-a-gutter-to-a-richedit.html), see Ferruccio Accalai's example near the end.

Comment: Lebeau: You gave a good idea.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I've found a simple solution for my short-term need.

As I mentioned before, the second RichEdit's scroll bar should be enabled for receiving WM_MOUSEWHEEL message, but I don't like both edit have scroll bar displayed. For this reason, I use EM_LINESCROLL instead to replace the mouse wheel message. I write a sub class derive the TRichEdit and overwrite its WM_MOUSEWHEEL handler, then pass EM_LINESCROLL message with the mouse wheel's delta value to both RichEdits.

```
int zDelta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(Message.WParam);
int scroll = zDelta == -120 ? 1 : -1;

SendMessage(MainEdit->Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, scroll);
SendMessage(IndexEdit->Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, scroll);
```

This makes the text vertical offset in RichEdits be aligned. But I think there must be better solution, I will keep research for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Sooner or later a solution will come.
My solution for c/c++ (you need to adapt as per your language you program):

```
   case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        POINTL pt;
        SendMessage(hRichMain,EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, LPARAM(&pt));
        SendMessage(hRichComp,EM_SETSCROLLPOS,0,LPARAM(&pt));
        SendMessage(hRichOffset,EM_SETSCROLLPOS,0,LPARAM(&pt));
        SendMessage(hRichAscii,EM_SETSCROLLPOS,0,LPARAM(&pt));

    break;
```

`EM_GETSCROLLPOS` copies scrollbar position from handle `hRichMain` to `pt`.
`EM_SETSCROLLPOS` sets the position information from `pt` to `hRichComp,hRichOffset, hRichAscii`.

and even more granular filtering possible via WM_COMMAND:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    {


///// RICH EDIT //////////////
      switch(HIWORD(wParam))
      {
          case EN_VSCROLL:
            if(LOWORD(wParam) == ID_RICHMAIN)
            {
                SendMessage(hRichMain,EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, LPARAM(&pt));
                SendMessage(hRichOffset,EM_SETSCROLLPOS,0,LPARAM(&pt));
                SendMessage(hRichAscii,EM_SETSCROLLPOS,0,LPARAM(&pt));
            //if (Button_GetCheck(hCheckScroll))
                SendMessage(hRichComp,EM_SETSCROLLPOS,0,LPARAM(&pt));

            }
            return TRUE;
      }
```